# How to subtract a streaming Dataframe from another one in pyspark?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, subtraction

I have the following code to ingest streaming data:

```
stream = spark.readStream \
  .format("cloudFiles") \
  .option("cloudFiles.format", "csv") \
  .option("header", "true") \
  .option('badRecordsPath',bad_records_path) \
  .schema(schema) \
  .load(landing_data_location)

display(stream)
```

And get the dataframe like this:

```
+---+------+--------------------+
| id|amount|                  ts|
+---+------+--------------------+
|  1|    20|2022-06-01 13:58:...|
|  2|    20|2022-06-01 13:58:...|
|  3|    20|2022-06-01 13:58:...|
+---+------+--------------------+
```

Then I validate the data using a sql statement:

```
stream.createOrReplaceTempView("events")
valid_records = spark.sql('select * from events e where e.id<>1')
display(valid_records)
```

The result will be like this:

```
+---+------+--------------------+
| id|amount|                  ts|
+---+------+--------------------+
|  2|    20|2022-06-01 13:58:...|
|  3|    20|2022-06-01 13:58:...|
+---+------+--------------------+
```

Then I try to use subtract to get the rest data in the Dataframe:

```
invalid_records = stream.subtract(valid_records)
display(invalid_records)
```

The follow error occurs:

```
AnalysisException: Except on a streaming DataFrame/Dataset on the right is not supported;
```

So my question is: what's the correct way to subtract a streaming Dataframe from another one?